# View class dispatch() doesn't find method?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I'm trying to use single url with two views. I found an example of that on official django documentation. I have something like this:

```
class DetailOrderView(View):
    """Combines form and detail parts into one and in darkness binds                                                                                  
    them."""

    # import pdb; pdb.set_trace()                                                                                                                     

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        view = DisplayDetailOrderView.as_view()                                                                                                     
        return view(self, *args, **kwargs)                                                                                                          

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        view = FormDetailOrderView.as_view()
        return view(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

And in urls.py I refer to DetailOrderView.as_view()

However, when I try to run this I get this error:

```
.... lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 84, in dispatch
if request.method.lower() in self.http_method_names:
AttributeError: 'DetailOrderView' object has no attribute 'method'
```

Which basically means when `dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs)` tries to call `request.method.lower()` it finds that request has no attribute `method`! Which is kinda strange right?

request should be defined in `as_view()` right?

This is pretty much c/p from the official documentation and it should work so I must be doing something stupid..

Comment: Yes, but now you *call* the view with `self`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that you need to use `.as_view()` first, but you call the `view` 
 function with `self` as first argument. The first argument of a `view` function is the request, so:

```
class DetailOrderView(View):
    """Combines form and detail parts into one and in darkness binds
    them."""

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        view = DisplayDetailOrderView.as_view()
        return view(request, *args, **kwargs)  # no self

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        view = FormDetailOrderView.as_view()
        return view(request, *args, **kwargs)  # no self
```

Note that this still can go wrong, since if the `DisplayDetailOrderView` for example has other URL parameters, it is possible that this view can not process the data correctly.

Although calling another view is *technically* possible, is is not very common.

Comment: Yes it should be `request` instead of `self`. What's funny is that I've spent better part of yesterday trying to figure this out.

Comment: @poppycockears: aarrghh.. And I did not include it in the example :) fixed now.

Comment: Which URL parameters do you mean? So if ie `DisplayDetailOrderView` had some `post` stuff it would fail?

Comment: @poppycockears: no, if the url is like `path('foo/<int:bar>/', some_view)`, then `**kwargs` will contain a parameter `'bar'`: that maps to the int "shipped" by the URL. It is possible that your `DisplayDetailOrderView` has differrent URL parameters.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem im i missing something here or is `super()` that is needed??

Comment: @JavierBuzzi: no, super is when you call the implementation of the *parent* view, here we want to redirect calls to *another* view. Note that `DisplayDetailOrderView` is not the same as `DetailOrderView`.

Comment: Ah. i see, i was missing something :P